# Mutiple inheritance of Interfaces in Blazor razor file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, multiple-inheritance

I have Blazor component that has only a razor file (without razor.cs code behind) and want the component to be inherited from an interface, first I tried the following :

**MyComponent.razor :**

```
  @inherits IMyInterface
```

Then after build I got an error in the .cs generated code(by Visual Studio) and I realized the component is only derived form my interface and not `ComponentBase` class. Here is the generated code:

```
...
public partial class MyComponent: IMyInterface
    {
        #pragma warning disable 1998
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
        {
        }
        #pragma warning restore 1998
    }
...
```

so I got the **'no suitable method found to override'** error.

then I tried the following codes and got a compile error with all of them :

```
// 1) multiple inheritance
@inherits ComponentBase,IMyInterface

// 2) adding semicolon 
@inherits ComponentBase,IMyInterface;

// 3) mutiple @inherits directive
@inherits ComponentBase
@inherits IMyInterface
```

The problem solved by adding a code behind file *MyComponent.razor.cs* and write the inheritance code there but I wonder that **is it possible to have multiple inheritance of interfaces in a razor file?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Multiple inheritance is not possible in C#, and Blazor template generates C# classes. So you can not `inherits` multiple base classes. However, you can `@implements` multiple interfaces.

An example would be as follows:

```
@implements IEventListener
@implements IInterface
```

I guess it is just a confusion over terms. You `inherit` a class but you `implement` an interface